# How to abort process in terminal without using CTRL key?

Tags: macos

I have CTRL key broken in my MBP. Is there any way to terminate process in terminal without it? I mean, can I change CTRL + C shortcut, or use mouse, or whatever? I know, I can use Karabiner to reassign CTRL globally, but this solution doesn't fit to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On OS X, you can use command-period. Additionally, you can use `stty intr <something>` to set a different interrupt character for the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
<Alt><SysRq><k>
```

Kill all processes (including X) which are running on the currently active virtual console. This key combination is know as "secure access key" (SAK).

Comment: Excuse me for stupid question, but where is <SysRq> key?

Comment: it suppose to be you print screen key too, check this link for more info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_request

Comment: On a standard Mac keyboard (especially one that's built into the MacBookPro -- where is "SysRq" key? no key labeled thus. There's also nothing like "print-screen" key to the best of my knowledge. What's the mapping here?

Comment: even on that Wikipedia entry you post here - it says this is no longer supported... and no mention at all for MacOS. I tried, and MacOS "rings" on the key combination - it doesn't recognize it. (supposedly the mapping should be physically the same on my 101 keys keyboard - to the "F13" above the arrows area.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can open another terminal and with the command `ps aux` you can find the process ID (column named PID) related to application that you want to kill and kill it with the command `kill PID`.

Comment: `pgrep` is also useful for finding the PID.